# MissingPluginException occured in flutter while using audio plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I wanna use this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/radio_player) and just executed [example code](https://github.com/cheebeez/radio_player/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart).

Then I get error

```
Another exception was thrown: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel radio_player/metadataEvents) 
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'property': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 17.. 
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'channel': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 17..
```

I already did

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. flutter run
4. restart vscode